# What is the actual size of a nucleotide?

Tags: nucleic-acids, 3d-structure

I found in this [website](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080313122043AA3Ls3F) that the dimension of a nucleotide is 0.34 nm. Is there any experimental paper confirming this statement?

Comment: This site might be able to help you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_Structure_of_Nucleic_Acids:_A_Structure_for_Deoxyribose_Nucleic_Acid.  If you are collecting facts at Yahoo Answers, why not ask the people who posted there where they got their numbers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dimension? The molecule is not circular; do you mean the longest dimension? or the van der Waals radius?

Comment: I know it is not circular, rather a flattish molecule with different conformations; but a sphere is still a good approximation. Van der Waals is probably the best measure.

Answer (score 3):

If you want experimental papers, we should be precise about what we're measuring. "The dimension of a nucleotide" is rather imprecise, as a nucleotide is a rather oblong, knobbly thing.

0.34 nm *is* a relevant measurement related to nucleotides, but it's specifically the distance between consecutive bases in a standard B-form DNA helix - that is, what's the spacing between the "rungs" on a DNA ladder.

This measurement can be confirmed by several experiments, primarily those involving X-ray or neutron crystallography or scattering. For example, both the [Wilkins](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/171738a0) and [Franklin](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/171740a0) papers that were published back-to-back with the famous Watson & Crick DNA structure paper referrence the strong 0.34 nm reflections from X-ray fiber diffraction which [Watson & Crick](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/171737a0) reference as the spacing of the bases in their model of DNA structure. Other papers have confirmed the measurement. [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6639645) 1983 *Biomed Biochim Acta* paper uses wide-angle X-ray scattering to find it. Additionally, there are a large number of structures in the [Protein Databank](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do) which contain DNA structures - these have been determined by a number of different approaches (X-ray crystallography, neutron diffraction, NMR, electron microscopy, etc.) and all of which are consistent with the 0.34 nm average spacing of base pairs. (Modulo minor structure-to-structure variations.)

Comment: this is for a polymer of nucleotides, how big is an individual nucleotide though?

Comment: It's for an individual nucleotide within a polymer, yes. But if that doesn't work for you, how do you want to measure it? As mentioned, a nucleotide is a rather oblong knobbly thing - the size depends on which direction you're measuring it in. Additionally, molecules don't have well-defined surfaces, being made mostly of electron clouds. There's conventions for the standard surface, but if you want experimental references, you have to specify an experimentally measurable distance.